# How to store hidden fields inside message in web application?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have web app (laravel 5.3, mysql) where users can comment any entity in project (almost every page contains something like chat)

I want to add possibility to mention other users inside message via '@' symbol ("Hello, @John, see here", for example).

When this message is posted to chat user named John must get notification about new message (via email, if he is offline).

Every message is connected to some page (/object/45, for example), so when email is sent user will know the page where he was mentioned.

The question is how to store this inside database?

`message` field has type `text`

In this example row would contain this data "Hello, @John, see here" (without quotes).

Problem is that there can be many users with name "John" so I can not not do simple:

```
 select email from users where username = 'John' -- email is used as login
```

Also username can be something like `@John Malkovich`, so I have to parse string to find out, if "John" or "John Malkovich" was mentioned.

What is unique - user id.

So how to store this inside database?

Possible solution:

`Hello, [user=34], see here` - field in database

Parse string before displaying to web browser and replace this string with

`Hello, @John, see here`

but, obviously, no one can paste literal text '[user=123]' inside message, because it would be interpreted as userid.

P.S. Inside one message many users can be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create something like `<span value="user34">John Malkovich</span>` and parse the value?

Or `<span data-user-id="user34">John Malkovich</span>` is probably better semantically.

Have absolutely no experience in this kind of stuff though, so don't take me too seriously ;)

Comment: It does not differ from my solution.

Comment: Well it does somewhat. The user doesn't see the `value` or the `data-user-id` and you can easily parse that in JavaScript or your backend.